# Please make [outlook-on-the-web] a synonym of [outlook-web-access]

Tags: support, status-completed, synonym-request

Currently `outlook-on-the-web` tag have 15 questions and `outlook-web-access` tag have 32 questions. Uses for the both tag is almost same.

Please make [outlook-on-the-web](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/outlook-on-the-web/info) a synonym of [outlook-web-access](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tags/outlook-web-access/info) and merge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[outlook-on-the-web](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook-on-the-web) has been merged with [outlook-web-access](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook-web-access) and a synonym created.